# Concat text() lines xpath of same div

Tags: xpath

I have this html block :

[image]

```html
<div class="more">
      Les quantités de <b>Manganèse</b> récupérées par les Mineurs sont augmentées de 150 %.
      <div class="more-infos">
                  <p>Quête : Offrande à Icleen</p>
                  <div class="more-infos-content">
                          <img src="http://staticns.ankama.com/dofus/www/game/items/200/39397.w75h75.png">
                        <p class="fleft">
               Récupérer 15 Manganèse et rapporter l'offrande à Théodoran Ax             </p>
                  </div>
        
      </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to get only the "Les quantités de **Manganèse** récupérées par les Mineurs sont augmentées de 150 %".

I tried : //*[@class="more"]/text() which gives me only the first line "Les quantités de "

Then when I try : //*[@class="more"]/text()[2] it gives me the second line (Manganèse...[...])

How can I get the full sentence between class="more" and class="more-infos" ?
Or how could I concatenate the text()[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TU7zf.png) + text()[2] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this expression

```
//div[@class="more"]/text() | //b/text()
```

Comment: Hi, it's nearly there, but it ommits everything after the <b> tag

Comment: Hmm on XPathtester it works, without a link to a page it's hard to suggest an answer.

Comment: I'm trying it on this page : http://www.krosmoz.com/fr/almanax?game=dofus

Comment: Okay it works great, it was in my php code, I kind of stored stuff in a array but allways looked at array[0] which was the first sentence before <b> tag. Thanks alot mate !

Comment: No problem, you can try to use a more specific expression like this: `//div[@class="more"]/text() | //div[@class="more"]/b/text()`

Comment: or you could also try: `//div[@class="more"]//text()[ancestor::div[1][@class="more"]]`

Answer (score 0):

The solution using the [***preceding axis***](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes) and [***string-join***](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-string-join) function:

```
string-join(//div[@class="more"]/div[@class="more-infos"]/preceding::text(), '')
```

***XPath*** result:

```
 Les quantités de Manganèse récupérées par les Mineurs sont augmentées de 150 %.
```

Comment: Hey Bud, I'm using php for this xpath query, I've tryed it, it gives me a php error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '')'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING). I have tryed it on online xpath tester and it works but not in my php, any ideas ? Is there a special quote or something to add in php ? Here's my php file (nothing special) http://pastebin.com/0HqsRdhh

Comment: @Niiw, you have errors in your code(single quotes).

Comment: could you tell me which part is wrong actually ? Can't find how to make it work, I tryed using double quotes instead of single but still get some error..